# How to get the remote user from Ejb context in JBoss

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0

I have a web application on Jboss 4.2.2 and in its login sequence I have added a custom login module. In the getIdentity() of this module, for some reason I need to change it to be other than the username entered in the login form.
 On any jsp page, I can get this identity with no problem by r`equest.getRemoteUser()`. However, when I tried to retrieve this value in an EJB using `ctx.getCallerPrincipal().getName()` , it returns the username entered in the login form. So I would like to ask in what ways can I get the identity I expected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be a bug on jboss

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/EJBTHREE-1756?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel